# How to accept "$10,000" formatted input for Decimal attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

My model has:

```
validates :budget,  :numericality => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0.01},
                    :presence => true,
                    :format => { :with => /^[$]?([0-9][0-9]?([,][0-9]{3}){0,4}([.][0-9]{0,4})?)$|^[$]?([0-9]{1,14})?([.][0-9]{1,4})$|^[$]?[0-9]{1,14}$/ }
```

but submitting a form with a value with a dollar sign or commas causes it to set :budget to `0.0`.

What's the best / cleanest way to accept values like `$1,000` into this decimal column? *(I format the output as currency, elsewhere, in a decorator).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you care to do is save the raw value, you can create a custom setter:

```
def budget= value
  write_attribute :budget, value.scan(/[0-9]/).join.to_f
end
```

But if you plan to do more with currencies in your project, I would highly recommend checking out the [money-rails](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails) gem. It gives you parsers, validators, arithmetic operators and much more to deal with currencies.

Comment: Caused a stack-too-deep loop. `write_attribute :budget, value.to_s.scan(/[0-9\.]/).join.to_f` worked like a charm tho (after I added `\.` to the regex). Update, and I'll accept.

Comment: That'll have to be decided once I get deeper into my accounting system. I haven't read up on it deeply, yet.